# Options to get my custom post type metadata via the WordPress API

Tags: post-meta, metabox, rest-api, api, json

I am using a plugin that adds multiple custom post types all of which have their own meta-data. I am able to expose the custom post type to WordPress's API but the metadata collected with those post is not.

For example "Team Members" is a post type and it is declared in the `team.php` file. I was able to add it to the WP API via `'show_in_rest' => true,` there is also a `team-metaboxes.php` which I tried to add the same attribute to by am not seeing it in the API JSON.

I am seeing the team metadata in the `wp_postmeta` table in the DB but I am having a hard time accessing it via the API.

What are my options. As of now I am using:

```
http://cmyk-demo.ra/wp-json/wp/v2/team-post/
```

But am not sure how to get the metadata for the team-post content types.

Per a recommendation below I have added the following snippet to my themes functions.php and still no meta data in the JSON returned from the API:

```
register_meta('post', 'fb_si', [
    'object_subtype' => 'team-post',
    'show_in_rest' => true
]);
```

The fact that the metaboxes are added via a plugin would that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [register_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#comment-2933) to add the meta field to the rest controller. Here the example from the link to expose the field `my_meta` of the  custom post type `my_article`:

```
register_meta('post', 'my_meta', [
  'object_subtype' => 'my_article',
  'show_in_rest' => true
]);
```

Comment: See my edit above regarding the snippet of code I added to my functions.php found in my themes root. I am not seeing the `fb_si` field in my JSON. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah it could be an issue depending on where the plugin is really storing the data. Are you sure is stored in `post_meta`?